# Pass AMPScript variable to client-side Javascript code in separate JS file

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, cloudpage

As above mentioned in the title, I'm trying to pass an **AMPScript variable**, which is a value coming from a data extension. The AMPScript block remains in the HTML code.
On the other hand, I have a **client-side** JavaScript code to plot a chart using this field. The JS code remains in a **separate JS file** which is referenced using `<script></script>` tag.

I know that is posible to pass AMPScript variables to client-side JS when the script is directly typed in the HTML file, **but this is not the case**. I tried to adapt this well-known case to my situation but I was not successfull.
Is it posible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292372/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-script-tag. You can set the script tag to contain an attribute that passes this value to your linked script file.

Comment: It worked like a charm...!